# ajax and xml - find multiple data and use it globally

Tags: ajax, xml

I have very large xml file with a lot of different data, as you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ef00Lptr/), I have aggregate_txts, aggregate_names, aggregate_dimensions, aggregate_links and process_steps as parent and for each parent a lot of different child data.

My question is, can I call all 5 parent elements, like this

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'steel_en_process.xml',
        dataType: "xml",
        success: loadDiagramData
      });
      function loadDiagramData(xml) {

        $(xml).find("aggregate_txts").each(function ();
        $(xml).find("aggregate_names").each(function ();
        $(xml).find("aggregate_dimensions").each(function ();
        $(xml).find("aggregate_links").each(function ();
        $(xml).find("process_steps").each(function ();
```

and later, when I need single child element, for example Pfannenbehandlung_05_txt from aggregate_txts to do like this (outside the parent)?

```js
var pfannen = $(this).find('Pfannenbehandlung_05_txt').text();

$('#clickAreas').prepend('<p> ' + pfannen + '</p>');
```

Or I must to define variables within the parent data like this

```js
$(xml).find("aggregate_txts").each(function();
    var pfannen = $(this).find('Pfannenbehandlung_05_txt').text();

    $('#clickAreas').prepend('<p> ' + pfannen + '</p>');
```